Formulas with whole column references too slow. Is it bad practice?
I used XLOOKUP referencing a whole column C:C. It makes the spreadsheet very slow.
Changing the reference to a fixed range $C$1:$C$300 solved that issue and now the spreadsheet works fine.
Found several posts 1, 2 on this topic and I guess that some formulas check the Worksheet.UsedRange property before evaluating the expression, while other formulas evaluate all the BLANK rows available in the spreadsheet.
Is using formulas with whole column references like SUM(C:C) bad practice?
*EDIT: LOOKUP formula looked at whole columns in two tabs, e.g.
=XLOOKUP(Tab1!A2, Tab2!B:B, Tab2!C:C, [if_not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])


Instead of referencing the whole range, use Structured References for the source data. It will be way faster and efficient. Also the advantage of using Tables is that formula adjust automatically when there is a change in the source data. Obviously, using SUM(C:C) is a bad practice and that is because your formula will not just iterate the rows where there is data, but it would also iterate through the empty cells where there is no data. better to use tables.

Most functions (not operators like * or +) will be fine with whole column references as they will only look at the usedrange of that column. What was your XLOOKUP formula?

Typically, it's a bad practice. Imagine doing a sumifs for a the whole column. You're telling check all these cells for this condition, so it keeps checking all the cells and then sums things up. A vlookup or xlookup will run until it finds a match then stop, so it's less straining, but with no match you can conclude it checked 1 million lines first. So if you have those references all over your spreadsheets it quickly becomes hundreds of millions of lines being validated every time the sheet needs to recalculate. Table references are much more dynamic and lean.
